# how to write a sql command to convert two sql columns and include a calculation in same query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports

Following is my code :

```
SELECT sum_date, sum_accname, sum_description,
CASE WHEN debit NOT LIKE '%[^.0-9]%'
     THEN CAST(debit as DECIMAL(9,2)) 
     ELSE NULL 
   END  AS debit,
CASE WHEN credit NOT LIKE '%[^.0-9]%'  
     THEN CAST(credit as DECIMAL(9,2)) 
     ELSE NULL 
   END  AS credit
FROM sum_balance
```

while viewing the report it shows an error : Error converting data type varchar to numeric. And i need sum of credit and debit column in the same query. Tried with the above code if i include only one column in the query for conversion its working bt adding another column in conversion it shows the error. I can't figure out the problem

Comment: You can try the ISNUMERIC() function, but it's not 100% fool-proof either.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `debit` and `credit` columns are text and thus can contain anything.  You're attempting to limit it to only numeric values with `NOT LIKE '%[^.0-9]%'` but that's not enough because you could have a value like `12.3.6.7` which cannot convert to a decimal.

There is no way in SQL Server that I'm aware of using `LIKE` to achieve what you're trying to achieve, because `LIKE` does not support the full range of regex operations -- in fact, it's quite limited.  In my opinion, you're torturing the database design by trying to multi-purpose those fields.  If you're looking to report on numeric data, then store them in numeric fields.  That assumes, of course, you have control over the schema.

Comment: can you share a example in which this will fail `NOT LIKE '%[^.0-9]%'`

Comment: is there any simple ways to convert lengthy numbers to numeric in sql query

Comment: @user3844217 - Unless you show what is present in `credit` and `debit` column it can't be fixed. What roryap said is one example in that case your filter fails.

Comment: then what is the solution for this

Comment: @user3844217 -- the solution, as I've said in my answer (updated a couple minutes ago), is that you need to store data in numeric fields if you want to use it for numeric operations.

Comment: is there anyway to use like a stored procedure to get the datas to my report

Comment: I don't know.  Is there?

Comment: I think my code is ok while i am checking my table there are some rows shows empty. After removing those rows its working. Thanks @roryap for your time and support